# Fluent validation to compare properties from two list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I'm working lots of complicated Validation Rules. We are using Fluent Validation to help with this and its a wonderful tool. I have a class which contains two list of same type.

```
    public class BookingDto
    {
        public IEnumerable<Trip> OutTripDetails { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Trip> InTripDetails{ get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Trip
    { 
    
     public DateTime? TravelDate { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<ClassTst> Stops { get; set; }   
    }
```

```
if (OutTripDetails .TravelDate != null && InTripDetails.TravelDate != null)
{
    if (InTripDetails.TravelDate < (DateTime)OutTripDetails .TravelDate)
    {
        Console.Writeline("Error here with date");
    }
}
```

I want to convert the above validation to use fluentvalidation

```
 RuleForEach(m => m.BookingDto.OutTripDetails )
                .ChildRules(r => r.RuleFor(t => t.TravelDate )   
 // .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(r => r.)
//RuleForEach(m => m.BookingDto.InTripDetails)
                .ChildRules(r => r.RuleFor(t => t.TravelDate )
```

Can I achieve this validation check with fluentvalidation in c#? I hav tried to implemnet with when condition to check if it is null but i couldnt make it work, Can someone hlp me to do this.

Comment: That validation (the one without FluentValidation) doesn't really make sense on `IEnumerable<Trip>`. It would on two `Trips`, though. Can I conclude that 1. Each of those lists shall have same Count _and_ 2. For each respective item at some index i the above validation shall pass?

Comment: Functionality is like i am travlling from stationA to stationB (InTripDetails) and  my return journey from StationB to StationA. (OutTripDetails )..so it is like my return journies travel date should be always greater than my first trip (station A to station B) .

Comment: @Fildor ......yes

Comment: When I was working for company, once, they flew me to Manila via Hong Kong. On the way back, the flight went via Taipeh and Zurich. In-Count = 2, Out-Count = 3 ... If this won't apply to your domain, then you are lucky ... but maybe this makes your problem even easier: Then earliest date in `out` must be after the latest date in `in`, right? You cannot go home, before you're there.

Comment: My actual scenario has th sam condition as you have mentioned. there can be multiple station in between . But the return trips datetime will always be grater in the real scenario. First i need to finish the trip to hong kong before i start my rturn trip back to Manila...

Comment: I don't know if this is a good fit for FluentValidation, actually. I am wondering if it would be easier to just create a custom "Must..." Validation for the BookingDto type to check exactly that. Or maybe a Custom Validator: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html#writing-a-custom-validator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251732/discussion-between-jubi-and-fildor).

Comment: You can try the pattern match of lists. Like `outtrip is intrip`, but im not sure if this will work on dotnet 6, it works on dotnet 7

Comment: Try this `RuleForEach(m => m.OutTripDetails)
            .Must(outTrip =>
            {
                var inTrip = m.InTripDetails.FirstOrDefault();
                if (outTrip.TravelDate.HasValue && inTrip.TravelDate.HasValue)
                {
                    return inTrip.TravelDate >= outTrip.TravelDate;
                }

                return true;
            })
            .WithMessage("In trip travel date must be greater than or equal to out trip travel date");`